# Executing a console app through AWS CodeDeploy doesn't work, but manually running the batchfile does?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, console-application, nancy, aws-code-deploy

I have a Nancyfx console application, which I'm trying to deploy to an AWS EC2 Windows instance using AWS CodeDeploy. All steps show a successful run in CodeDeploy's Deployment dashboard, though the application is not actually starting correctly.

The problem is isolated to the ApplicationStart hook, which is a one line batch file that runs the application's exe. If I RDP into the instance and run the batch file manually, it operates as expected.

Expected Result:
- The application's console window opens
- Debug printouts indicate pulling some initial data from DynamoDB was successful
- Debug printout indicates the application is running.
- Console window is held open by waiting for any input (Nancyfx's default setup)

Actual Result:
- No console window opens, but CodeDeploy's logs show the stdout for the following
- Debug printouts indicate pulling the initial data failed
- Debug printout indicates the application is running
- Application is not running

I guess the problem lies with how CodeDeploy is executing the batchfile, but I couldn't find answers for such a specific and hard-to-Google problem. Please help!

Comment: Are you running with an IAM Instance for code deploy? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-ec2-configure.html

Comment: Yep, otherwise I don't think the transfer from S3 would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - I discovered that DynamoDB calls within the application were causing it to exit prematurely, which was resolved by giving the IAM role DynamoDB access.